# Creating a multi-lined textbox/textfield in C++, not VC++

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, textbox

I was wondering how to create a text box that can respond to the "enter" key and create a new line just like the field I am typing in now. 
`CreateWindow ("edit", 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 5, 5, 130, 20, hwnd, (HMENU) 1000, GetModuleHandle (NULL), NULL);`
That is what I have currently, but when I create it, it is a tiny strip and when I press the "Enter" key, it does not jump down to the next line like a paragraph. Any ideas? I am using C++ not VC++ or any .net framework and I am on Windows 7. Thank you.

Comment: (1) There's no such language as VC++. (2) Which framework are you going to use? I assume WinAPI would work the same way with any compiler.

Comment: @Vlad I think he means "No MFC" by "No VC++"

Comment: @Brandon: well, I believe you are right. The art of proper answering includes some telepathy :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, I commonly refer to Visual Studio with VC++ for Visual C++. I guess MFC is more correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the "ES_MULTILINE" flag. See [Edit Control Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the great reference.